# Eclipse Does Not Generates Proper Java methods for the Scenarios in Cucumber Feature File

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, cucumber

I am trying to generate methods for the steps in my feature file and in the console I am getting something like this

```
 Given("I navigate to facebook", () -> {
     //write code here....
 throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
 });
```

What I want to have is:

```
@Given("^I navigate to facebook$")
```

I know about the Tidy Gherkin, But I want to have my methods generated in the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If u removed the cucumber java8 jar dependency and just include the plain old cucumber java, guess it would spit out the snippet format u r looking for.

Comment: Tried that nothing has changed.

Comment: What version r u using?

Comment: Tried different versions -- none worked